# installed openVPN, my ip hasn't changed and command on terminal says dead

Tags: openvpn

I just installed openVPN, checked to see if it was working, my IP is the same, command in terminal says open VPN is "dead".  How do I fix, or revive?

Comment: Did you do anything other than installing OpenVPN? OpenVPN is a piece of VPN software. You have to configure it to connect to a remote server, and you need a remote server to connect to. Just installing OpenVPN doesn't activate any VPN connection.